# Bicubic interpolation the surface

Tags: c++, interpolation, surface, bicubic

Faced the problem of interpolating the surface with a cubic spline, dug the entire Internet, but except for the banal interpolation in the square [0,1] x [[0,1] did not find anything, but I need to interpolate the value inside an arbitrary region (whether 16 points or 4 with the indication of all the derivatives, etc.), I give an example:
We take points that satisfy the equation of an elliptic paraboloid: x = {100..102}, y = {100..102}

x = 100, y = 100, f (x, y) = 1805.56

x = 100, y = 101, f (x, y) = 1816.72

x = 100, y = 102, f (x, y) = 1828

x = 101, y = 100, f (x, y) = 1830.68

x = 101, y = 101, f (x, y) = 1841.85

x = 101, y = 102, f (x, y) = 1853.12

x = 102, y = 100, f (x, y) = 1856.06

x = 102, y = 101, f (x, y) = 1867.22

x = 102, y = 102, f (x, y) = 1878.5

How can I calculate the value at the point {101.5, 101.5}?
I read the article on wikipedia, but there's nothing said about how it works at arbitrary points, outside the square [0,1] x [0,1]
A good implementation that works on a single quadrate and uses a consistent interpolation here

```
double cubicInterpolate (double p[4], double x) {
    return p[1] + 0.5 * x*(p[2] - p[0] + x*(2.0*p[0] - 5.0*p[1] + 4.0*p[2] - 
p[3] + x*(3.0*(p[1] - p[2]) + p[3] - p[0])));
}

double bicubicInterpolate (double p[4][4], double x, double y) {
    double arr[4];
    arr[0] = cubicInterpolate(p[0], y);
    arr[1] = cubicInterpolate(p[1], y);
    arr[2] = cubicInterpolate(p[2], y);
    arr[3] = cubicInterpolate(p[3], y);
    return cubicInterpolate(arr, x);
}
```

Comment: 101.5 seems to be inside the square extents of 100 to 102.

Comment: The matter is that if if the above points are put in the array p, then the interpolation does not work, since the coefficients others should be some

Comment: Often, these basic interpolation formulae are expressed using a 1x1 square starting at the origin. You may need to shift and rescale your x & y coordinates to make the formulae apply to each square within your grid.

Comment: @rwp I tried to divide each coordinate so that they take a value from 0 to 1, say a certain multiplier SCALE, the algorithm works on this given pair of coordinates, but how then to return to normal scale? f (with * scale, and * scale) !== scale * f (x, y)